# Binance Announcement

Tags: binance

Binance announces their new listings on this API endpoint

https://www.binance.com/gateway-api/v1/public/cms/article/list/query?type=1&catalogId=48&pageNo=1...

But I've noticed that the API endpoint only reflects an announcement around 30 seconds after their post is marked as being published.

For example, Binance just announced they will be listing JASMY. You can see in this article https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/f86958f1977248a691d752da735be408 that the officially stated time of posting was 2:59AM EST. However, the post did not show on the API results until 3:00:14AM EST. That's anywhere from a 15 second to a 74 second gap.

Does anyone know an API endpoint or url that has the information closer to that stated time of 2:59AM EST?